# Servlet's sendRedirect() kills my session attributes

Tags: java, session, servlets, attributes

I am working on a webapp in WinXP, Eclipse Indigo and Google web plugin.

I have a simple form that takes a value from user (e.g email) , passes it to a servlet named `SignIn.java` that processes it and saves the email value to the session. 
The `SignIn` code is very simple , here is what its `doGet` mostly does:

```
String email = req.getParameter("email");   //getting the parameter from html form
...
...
HttpSession session = req.getSession();     //create a new session
session.setAttribute("email", email);
```

So far so good, I've verified that the values aren't `null` at this point. Now comes the problem, I want to redirect to another servlet (`ShowOnline.java`) that needs to do some more processing. When I write

```
resp.sendRedirect(resp.encodeRedirectURL("/ShowOnlineServlet"));
```

`ShowOnline` gets `null` session values (the same email attribute I saved a second before is now `null`)

When I write

```
getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ShowOnlineServlet");
```

everything is OK, the email attribute from before isn't `null`!

What is going on? `sendRedirect()` just makes your browser send a new request, it shouldn't affect the session scope. I have checked the cookies and they are fine (it is the same session from before for sure since it is the first and only session my webapp creates and furthermore I even bothered and checked the sesison ID's and they're the same on both requests).

Why would there be a difference between `sendRedirect()` and `forward()`? The easy solution would be to use `forward()` but I want to get to the bottom of this before I just let go , I think it is important for me to understand what happened. I'm not sure I like the idea of not knowing what's going on on such basic concepts (my whole webapp is very simple and basic at this point since I'm a beginner).

Any thoughts ideas or suggestions would be warmly welcome !

Comment: I guess it might be possible at the moment to use forward instead of sendredirect but I think later on I'd want to use sendredirect without fearing my session attributes would go null for no apparent reason .

Comment: @home: OP confirmed that session ID is the same before and after.

Comment: what happens when you don't send redirect and manually go to the /ShowOnlineServlet from the browser?

Comment: OK I think the problem might have been that I've created a non serializable object and stored it in the session .

Comment: It's VERY important to make sure your attributes implement Serializable interface , otherwise you'll get silly bugs (the frustrating thing is that locally everything works out fine but once you deploy to your server u might find null attributes ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `SignIn` servlet is only saving a request parameter (email), then you could also replace the servlet with a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info), e.g. `SignInFilter`.

`SignInFilter` would contain the same logic as your `SignIn` servlet (copying the email from the request parameters to the session), but would call the next item in the chain (which will be your `ShowOnline` servlet) instead of doing any redirect/forward.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) 
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    session.setAttribute("email", email);

    chain.doFilter(req, res); // continue to 'ShowOnline'

}
```

Set up your form to POST to the `ShowOnline` servlet instead, and configure your new SignInFilter to execute before `ShowOnline` (servlet mapping omitted below for brevity).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SignInFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.example.SignInFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SignInFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/ShowOnline</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score -2):

As far as my knowledge, sendRedirect() just redirects the control to another page without transfering the associated request & response object of parent page, but RequestDispatcher(object) will dispatch the ServletRequest and ServletResponse to the page mentioned in path argument { getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("path")} after that you can either forward the objects to that page or include the objects. So by this container becomes assured that he has to use the previous request and response object from of the parent page instead of creating new one.
Specially if you are using session management the best option is RequestDispatcher.

Hope that answers the question.

To All :- Please correct me if i am wrong.

@rs